# LINQ query decimal and return decimal converted to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Trying to use Linq to query a order total and return it back as a label.Text in asp.net

Page Load:

```
IQueryable<decimal> OrderTotal = GetTotal(orderId);
total.Text = OrderTotal.ToString();
```

Method:

```
public IQueryable<decimal> GetTotal(int? orderId)
{
    var q = _db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId).Select(x => x.Total);
    return q;
}
```

Result:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Total] AS [Total] FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[OrderId] = @p__linq__0
```

why doesn't this return the Total as number? Instead a T-Sql Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IQueriable<T>` interface refers to a sequence of `T`, not a single instance of `T`. If you're trying to get a single value from the database and set a single text box to that value, that won't work.

Change your method signature to

```
public decimal GetTotal(int? orderId)
{
    var q = _db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId).Select(x => x.Total);
    return q.FirstOrDefault();
}
```